# accessing an id within another id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get a block of code written in div then modify some of the div/id to different names and so I can send them to the form with unique names. Any ideas on how to do this?
My idea right now is to first set the variable to to the div that I'm copying then access the other div's within it, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
var i = 0;
    $("#custom_rates").click(function() 
    { 
        var sublet_dates_seen = $("#sublet_dates_seen").clone();
        // all id's below are within #sublet_dates_seen
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById('#CustomPricePerNightPrice').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][price][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateMonth').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][month][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateDay').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][day][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateYear').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][year][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateMonth').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][month][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateDay').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][day][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateYear').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][year][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightMinimumNights').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][minimum_nights][' + i ']');
        sublet_dates_seen.getElementById(('#CustomPricePerNightMaximumNights').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][maximum_nights][' + i ']');        
        sublet_dates_seen.appendTo(".avi_specialrates");
        i = i + 1;
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: `getElementById` is neither a jQuery function nor is it defined anywhere except on `document`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

Comment: As IDs have to be unique, it does not make sense to search for a certain ID inside an element. `$('#CustomPricePerNightPrice').attr(...)` should be just fine. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to mix DOM and jQuery in a wrong way. The [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method has to be used. Also, you've got too much parentheses at the middle of your code.

```
sublet_dates_seen.getElementById('#CustomPricePerNightPrice'); //WRONG
sublet_dates_seen.find('#customPricePerNight'); //Correct
```

The correct code:

```
var i = 0;
$("#custom_rates").click(function() 
{ 
    var sublet_dates_seen = $("#sublet_dates_seen").clone();
    // all id's below are within #sublet_dates_seen
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightPrice').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][price][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateMonth').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][month][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateDay').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][day][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightStartDateYear').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][start_date][year][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateMonth').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][month][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateDay').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][day][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightEndDateYear').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][end_date][year][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightMinimumNights').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][minimum_nights][' + i ']');
    sublet_dates_seen.find('#CustomPricePerNightMaximumNights').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][maximum_nights][' + i ']');        
    sublet_dates_seen.appendTo(".avi_specialrates");
    i = i + 1;
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to replace your getElementById calls with jQuery's .find() method: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Also, I believe .clone() returns an HTML element or set of elements, not a jQuery object, so you'd have to do something like this:

```
$(sublet_dates_seen).find('#CustomPricePerNightPrice').attr('name','data[CustomPricePerNight][price][' + i ']');
```